# copy column from other dataframe based on matching values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, where-clause

I have two dataFrames, one with iso codes and country names
and the other one with only country names.

I would like to add a new column to `df2` with the country names from `df1` if the values `df1.iso == df2.id` match.

`df1`

```
Country      iso    
Afghanistan  AFG       
Afghanistan  AFG       
Afghanistan  AFG       
...
```

and `df2`

```
id      
AFG     
AFG     
AFG     
AFG
...
```

I tried this:

`post['country'] = pre['Country'].where(pre['iso'] == post['id'])`

But I got an error

`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: You want to add map the values to df1 or df2?

Comment: I want df2 to have a column 'Country' where if the 'id' column of df2 matches the 'iso' column of df1 then the 'Country' column value at that record in df1 is copied into the matching line in df2. So all 'AFG' in df2 should have in the newly added 'Country' column 'Afghanistan' ... and so on for all rows (which contain all countries ISO codes of the world).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to **left** merge `df2` with `df1` after dropping duplicate values from `df1`:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), left_on='id',
                right_on='iso', how='left').drop('iso', 1)
```

Or, you can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the `Country` from `df1` to `df2` based on `iso` code:

```
df2['Country'] = df2['id'].map(df1.drop_duplicates().set_index('iso')['Country'])
```

Result:

```
print(df2)
    id      Country
0  AFG  Afghanistan
1  AFG  Afghanistan
2  AFG  Afghanistan
3  AFG  Afghanistan
```